# How to add an increasing index based on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, date, data-wrangling

I have a data frame that contains the columns "hour", "day","month" and "count".

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(0)

df <- expand_grid(expand_grid(
  hour = seq(0:23),
  day = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")),
  month = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun")) %>%
  mutate(count = sample(0:100, n(), replace = TRUE))

head(df)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 × 4
>    hour day   month count
>   <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
> 1     1 Mon   Jan      13
> 2     1 Mon   Feb      67
> 3     1 Mon   Mar      38
> 4     1 Mon   Apr       0
> 5     1 Mon   May      33
> 6     1 Mon   Jun      86
> ```

I would like to add a new column named "id" that contains an increasing index which can be used to sort the data in chronological order. The solution I found is not particularly concise and requires me to set factor levels before calling arrange(). Is there another way to solve this issue that capitalises on the fact that I am working with (unformatted) dates?

This is my solution with arrange():

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(day = factor(day, levels = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")),
  month = factor(month, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"))) %>%
  arrange(month, day, hour) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())

head(df2)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 × 5
>    hour day   month count    id
>   <int> <fct> <fct> <int> <int>
> 1     1 Mon   Jan      13     1
> 2     2 Mon   Jan      43     2
> 3     3 Mon   Jan      82     3
> 4     4 Mon   Jan      66     4
> 5     5 Mon   Jan      49     5
> 6     6 Mon   Jan      79     6
> ```

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You could use `month.abb` and `levels(lubridate::wday(Sys.Date(), label = TRUE, week_start = 1))` to save a bit of space/time.

Comment: Apart from the simplification suggested by @harre, I don't think you can do much better. Working with weekdays instead of days of month does not let you create a real date representation of your data frame rows.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer. I already suspected this and will make it work this way.